# Rank and unrank combinations to distribute k balls into n bins of different capacities

Tags: arrays, algorithm, math, combinations, combinatorics

I want to distribute `k` balls into `n` bins of different capacities. How can I rank and unrank the distributions given `n`, `k`, and the bin capacities?

Example:

`n := 3`

`k := 4`

`bin capacities := 3,2,1`

Balls in bins:

`1,2,1`, `2,1,1`, `2,2,0`, `3,0,1`, `3,1,0` := 5

Is there a formula?

Comment: What do you mean by rank and unrank? It looks like you want to count the number of ways k balls can be distributed to n bins where each bin holds a different, finite number of balls?

Comment: @doggie_breath When people say "rank and unrank" they usually mean put an order on the distributions of balls to bins, then be able to look at a distribution and say which one it is, and look at a number `m` and say which is the `m`th distribution.

Comment: It appears that the distribution `2,1,1` is missing.  I assume that the list is in lexicographic order and this should be second on the list?

Comment: @btilly ah gotcha. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Yes `2,1,1` was missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know if there is a standard name for this technique, but this is a kind of problem that I have successfully solved many times with a twist on dynamic programming.

What I do using dynamic programming to build a data structure from which the rank/unrank can happen, and then build logic to do the rank/unrank thing.

The dynamic programming piece is hardest.

```py
import collections
BallSolutions = collections.namedtuple('BallSolutions', 'bin count balls next_bin_solutions next_balls_solutions');

def find_ball_solutions (balls, bin_capacities):
    # How many balls can fit in the remaining bins?
    capacity_sum = [0 for _ in bin_capacities]
    capacity_sum[-1] = bin_capacities[-1]

    for i in range(len(bin_capacities) - 2, -1, -1):
        capacity_sum[i] = capacity_sum[i+1] + bin_capacities[i]

    cache = {}
    def _search (bin_index, remaining_balls):
        if len(bin_capacities) <= bin_index:
            return None
        elif capacity_sum[bin_index] < remaining_balls:
            return None
        elif (bin_index, remaining_balls) not in cache:
            if bin_index + 1 == len(bin_capacities):
                cache[(bin_index, remaining_balls)] = BallSolutions(
                    bin=bin_index, count=1, balls=remaining_balls, next_bin_solutions=None, next_balls_solutions=None)
            else:
                this_solution = None
                for this_balls in range(min([remaining_balls, bin_capacities[bin_index]]), -1, -1):
                    next_bin_solutions = _search(bin_index+1, remaining_balls - this_balls)
                    if next_bin_solutions is None:
                        break # We already found the fewest balls that can go in this bin.
                    else:
                        this_count = next_bin_solutions.count
                        if this_solution is not None:
                            this_count = this_count + this_solution.count
                        next_solution = BallSolutions(
                            bin=bin_index, count=this_count,
                            balls=this_balls, next_bin_solutions=next_bin_solutions,
                            next_balls_solutions=this_solution)
                        this_solution = next_solution
                cache[(bin_index, remaining_balls)] = this_solution
        return cache[(bin_index, remaining_balls)]

    return _search(0, balls)
```

Here is code to produce a ranked solution:

```py
def find_ranked_solution (solutions, n):
    if solutions is None:
        return None
    elif n < 0:
        return None
    elif solutions.next_bin_solutions is None:
        if n == 0:
            return [solutions.balls]
        else:
            return None
    elif n < solutions.next_bin_solutions.count:
        return [solutions.balls] + find_ranked_solution(solutions.next_bin_solutions, n)
    else:
        return find_ranked_solution(solutions.next_balls_solutions, n - solutions.next_bin_solutions.count)
```

Here is code to produce the rank for a solution.  Note that it will blow up if provided with an invalid answer.

```py
def find_solution_rank (solutions, solution):
    n = 0
    while solutions.balls < solution[0]:
        n = n + solutions.next_bin_solutions.count
        solutions = solutions.next_balls_solutions
    if 1 < len(solution):
        n = n + find_solution_rank(solutions.next_bin_solutions, solution[1:])
    return n
```

And here is some test code:

```py
s = find_ball_solutions(4, [3, 2, 1])
for i in range(6):
    r = find_ranked_solution(s, i)
    print((i, r, find_solution_rank(s, r)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define the number of such combinations recursively. Given `k` balls and bin capacities `q_1, ..., q_n`, for each `j` between `0` and`q_1`, place `j` balls in `q_1` and allocate the remaining `k-j` balls among other bins.

Here is a quick Python implementation:

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(None)
def f(n, *qs):
  if not qs:
    return 1 if n == 0 else 0
  q = qs[0]
  return sum(f(n-j, *qs[1:]) for j in range(q+1))

f(4, 3, 2, 1)
# 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way (in pseudocode), though it doesn't look very efficient. It would probably be smart to add some short-circuiting in places where the number of balls won't fit in the total remaining capacity. Perhaps some clever caching could help, if a given list of capacities will be used many times.

All numbers are non-negative integers. Function `ArrayTail(array a)` is the subarray whose elements are all elements of the input array after the first. Function `ArrayCon(number head, array a)` is the array whose elements are `head` followed by the elements of `a`.

```
function Count(array capacities, number balls) -> number
    If balls == 0:
       return 1
    Else if capacities is empty:
       return 0
    Else:
       Let sum: number
       sum <- 0
       For b from 0 to max(balls, capacities[0]):
           sum <- sum + Count(ArrayTail(capacities), b)
       End For
       return sum
    End If/Else
End function

function Rank(array capacities, array counts) -> number
    Precondition: length(capacities) == length(counts)
    Precondition: counts[i] <= capacities[i] for all i < length(counts)
    If counts is empty:
        return 0
    Else:
        Let total: number
        total <- 0
        For c in counts:
            total <- total + c
        End For
        Let r: number
        r <- Rank(ArrayTail(capacities), ArrayTail(counts))
        For b from 0 to (counts[0]-1):
            r <- r + Count(ArrayTail(capacities), total - b)
        End For
        return r
    End If/Else
End function

function Unrank(array capacities, number balls, number rank) -> array
    Precondition: rank < Count(capacities, balls)
    If capacities is empty:
        return empty array
    Else
        Let c0: number
        c0 <- 0
        Loop until "return":
            Let subcount: number
            subcount <- Count(ArrayTail(capacities), balls-c0)
            If subcount <= rank:
                c0 <- c0 + 1
                rank <- rank - subcount
            Else
                return ArrayCon(c0, Unrank(ArrayTail(capacities), balls-c0, rank))
            End If/Else
        End Loop
    End If/Else
End function
```