# Given n balls and m bins, each bin with a certain capacity, how many combinations are there?

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given n identical balls and m unique bins, where each bin has a certain capacity (from 0 to z, where z is a non-negative integer less than or equal to 15), how many different ways are there of distributing the balls? Is there a general purpose algorithm for solving this type of problem?

I have come across the "stars and bars" and "inclusion/exclusion" principle but I have also found some questions/answers here on stackoverflow, but none of the answers seem general enough to be extendable to arbitrary sizes of n. It seems that one way of solving it is with dynamic programming. How can this be done, for arbitrary n (the problem with the solution below is the recursion depth becomes too large in Python for relatively small n, such as n = 1000).

[Rank and unrank combinations to distribute k balls into n bins of different capacities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60268680/rank-and-unrank-combinations-to-distribute-k-balls-into-n-bins-of-different-capa)

Am I not understanding this correctly? Could someone explain it to me like you would to a five year old?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. The question and answer you link to seems to solve your problem as you've written it. What is different about your question?

Comment: Well, for instance, that's a recursive solution that cannot be programmatically solved for large values of n (recursion depth becomes too large). Is there another way of doing dynamic programming that enables it to be solved for arbitrary n?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be modeled by generating functions, where each bin yields a polynomial (1 + z + z<sup>2</sup> + … + z<sup>c</sup>) where c is the capacity of the bin, and we take the product of the bin polynomials and extract the coefficient of z<sup>n</sup>.

The straightforward non-recursive dynamic programming algorithm is to evaluate the product from left to right. If needed, you can get fancy and mix and match your multiplication algorithms, especially given that c ≤ 15.

Comment: That's how you would explain it to a five-year-old? :) Well, maybe not the typical five-year-old.

Comment: Okay, so if we have n = 3 and m = 3 with restrictions [3,3,2], we get the following:
(1+z+z²)*(1+z+z²+z³)². We expand this and the coefficient in front of z³ is the correct answer?

Did I get the idea right? Even if so, I have no clue how to implement a DP algorithm with this in front of me. Any ideas?

Comment: @tmpquestionwonderer7777272 The DP algorithm is just computing (1+z+z^2) (1+z+z^2) = (1+2z+3z^2+2z^3+z^4) then (1+2z+3z^2+2z^3+z^4) (1+z+z^2) = (1+3z+6z^2+7z^3+6z^4+3z^5+z^6) and so on, just extending the product one polynomial at a time.

Comment: Right. And then optimizations can be made, such as not evaluating past a certain order of z, i.e. if n = 6 then you don't really need to calculate anything past z⁶, right (which might happen if two separate constraints for the bins are ci = 4 and ci=3, which would produce an order of z⁷)? Is there an efficient algorithm to perform these computations?

Comment: @tmpquestionwonderer7777272 The basic multiply `r = p * q` looks like `r.degree = p.degree + q.degree; for (int i = 0; i <= p.degree; i++) for (int j = 0; j <= q.degree; j++) r.coef[i + j] += p.coef[i] * q.coef[j];`. For large polynomials, you can start to do things like Karatsuba and FFT.

Comment: Your suggestion should have a time complexity of O(n²), no?

Comment: Right, but that's only for performing the calculation once for 2 expressions of order c, i.e. (1+z+z²+...+z^c)*(1+z+...+z^c). This needs to be done for each constraint c, of which there are n. This means the time complexity for the full DP algorithm should be O(n*n²)=O(n³). Does that seem correct?

Comment: But shouldn't it be O(m*n²), where m is the number of bins? I mean don't we have to perform the nested for-loop for each bin?

Comment: @tmpquestionwonderer7777272 Sorry, O(n) for each multiplication (because c ≤ 15 and we're modding by z^(n+1)) and O(m) multiplications --> O(m n).

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but what actually is n in this case? Is it the number of balls n, or is it just some constant? If it's the number of balls, how come? Because we don't have to consider any z^n or higher order? Not sure if I'm understanding it entirely, hence the questions. My understanding is also that nested for-loops are always polynomial in some aspect, so I don't quite understand why it's not n² for each multiplication.

Comment: I implemented this in Python, but when I run it for large values of n and m, such as n = 943 and m = 100 where each bin has a max capacity of 15, I get the following massive value: 3135342913924558738904515949600304125063821468922675418916187764617836241168205883775473071309419880974583057947200

There can't possibly be that many combinations. What am I doing wrong here? Is there some overflow happening that I'm not aware of? Do the coefficients really grow that fast?

Comment: @tmp I could believe that value.

Comment: Is it possible to somehow include memorization to speed up the time complexity?

Comment: @tmpquestionwonderer7777272 It is memoized already. You could compute the product using divide and conquer (split the array in half; multiply the (recursively computed) product of the first half by the product of the second half), but past that, you'll need to implement a faster polynomial multiplication algorithm.

Comment: I am wondering, isn't the array symmetrical? If you have the first half figured out, can't you simply extend that first half into the second half without actually performing the calculations? Combinations work that way, 10C4 is the same as 10C6, but I don't know if the same applies here.

Comment: Also, because n = 15m in the worst case, does that not mean that the time complexity is in fact O(n * m) = O(15m * m) = O(15m²) <=> O(m²)?