# Trying to create a path algorithm for my game

Tags: algorithm, grid

I work on a game in which you have to fill a grid with a minimum of moves.

Here are the rules :

- Starting on the cell with a black square, we move on the grid
  horizontally or vertically.
- When we move on a cell we invert its    color (white cell becomes
  blue and blue cell becomes white).
- We can    move on a cell multiple times and each time we invert its
  color.

When
I generate a grid I need to know the minimum number of moves and
every solution.

My method is to suppose that the minimum of move is the number of white cells plus n = 0 blue cells ans to find solutions. If I don't then I try with n+1 blue cell etc.. For each hypothesis I create every possible path, and I have to gradually analyze them with an algorithm which will tell me if they are good or not.

My problem is that I don't know how to create the algorithm I need.

Let's take this grid for example :

[image]

To fill it the shortest way I have found (by trying) that the path has to go through 4 blue cells. There is several possible paths and all of them go through 4 blue cells, which become white and they go through them again.

I am trying to create that algorithm which will analyse the grid and will tell me how many blue cells has to be gone through, but I don't know how to make it.

Do you have leads on where to begin?

Thanks for reading me.

EDIT : here is a simulation if you want to test paths for the grid. http://simili-le-jeu.com/jeu3.html
And the grid with coordinates :

[image]

Comment: "When I generate a grid I need to know the minimum number of moves and every solution" -- what do you mean by *every*? There can be infinitely many. Do you want all minimum-length solutions, all minimal solutions (for some minimality criterion), or just one minimum length solution?

Comment: Yes I want all minimum length solutions, and for that my method is to suppose a minimal length and then a minimal number of blue cells I can go through. After that I will create, move after move, every possible path and after each move I will try to see if the paths generated are good or not. The algorithm I try to create would allow me to check if a path is good or not.

Comment: There can be a *very* large number of minimum length solutions. If the board starts with only the starting square colored blue, this is the same as [counting directed Hamiltonian paths on a grid graph](http://oeis.org/A096969). For a 10x10 board the answer has 15 digits, and the count grows *faster than exponentially*. If you want the paths themselves in addition to counts, you need to strongly restrict the allowed board configurations or sizes.

Comment: You are right, I will always have blue squares, at least one third of all the squares. And I will create no bigger than 6x6 or 7x7 boards. Thank you for the hamiltonian paths I will check it.

Answer (score 3):

The standard answer is an [A* search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm).  The nodes of the graph are patterns of blue/white, plus what square you are on.  The cost function is the number of white squares.  Two nodes are connected if you can get from one to the other with a node.

But you want the paths. I will recommend the following strategy. For each node in the graph (that is game state + where you are), you want to know the following facts:

1. The minimum cost to get there.
2. The nodes you can have arrived from.
3. How many minimum paths there are to this state.

For an `n*n` board there are theoretically `2^(2n) n` nodes you could be in. But, in fact, doing an A* search to discover the ones on the way to all blue will mean you skip most of them.  Once you have this data structure, working backwards from the end state(s) will let you reconstruct how many paths, and reconstruct any individual path.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60290205/585411 for an example of how this kind of "reconstruct the solutions" logic can work.

Comment: Thank you I will work this out and I will be back to tell you if I understand clearly what you propose.

Comment: To begin with the first part of your answer : you say that the nodes are the squares (blue or white), that the cost is the number of white squares. But don't you think the cost must be the number of white squares plus the number of moves? And you say that for two nodes to be connected they have to be linked by a third node? Or simply they have to touch each other vertically or horizontally? Path finding algorithms are new to me sorry.

Comment: About the strategy, you say that before each move I need to get for each node/square : the minimal cost in relation to where I am. The minimal cost is the distance from where I am plus the distance from the node? I don't understand the two other things I need to get. Maybe an example would help me figure it out. I will update the grid in my post with coordinates.

Comment: @RomainCharles The cost just has to be a lower bound for the cost.  It does not need to be exact.  The fact that it does not need to be exact makes it easier.  A better measure one for larger graphs will be the number of white squares plus 2* distance to the nearest white square - 2.

Comment: I am kind of lost in your explainaitions... do you think you could make an example?